# How to play sound with javascript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I made a chrome extension that has a popup window that contains a button, and when that button is pressed a sound should play. However, no sound plays when the button is pressed.
javascript file:

```
function playAudio(audioElementId)
{
    document.getElementById(audioElementId).play()
}
```

html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MainScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MainCSS.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="AudioFile" src="sound.wav"></audio>
    <button id="soundButton" onclick="playAudio('AudioFile')">Play Sound</button>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Play A Sound",
  "description": "plays a sound when button is pressed",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "background",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: is the missing `>` typo also in your code?

Comment: Can you check if `<button onclick="document.getElementById('AudioFile').play()">Play</button>` works. It appears the lack of `;` in your function call may be the issue, or even a `getElementById` not finding that ID (most likely some encode problem, or even typo somewhere).

Comment: I was actually originally using <button onclick="document.getElementById('AudioFile').play()">Play</‌​button>  But it wasn't working so I moved it to its own function.